# How to find the time difference when time is given

Tags: java

I have the time in the following format.

```
String deptTime ="08:00 PM";
String arrTime = "04:00 AM";
```

How to get the difference hours exactly in words like **1 hour 30 minutes** ..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are you arriving before you left? Are you expect the answer to be positive or negative?

Comment: Can I say: use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) before anyone else?

Comment: arrival time is tomorrow. I have solved it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use apache commons-lang jar file..
Take the deptTime and arrTime as **StringBuffer**

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String dateIs = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    if (departureTime.reverse().substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase(arrivalTime.reverse().substring(0,2))) {
        departureTime.reverse().insert(0, dateIs + " ");
        arrivalTime.reverse().insert(0, dateIs + " ");
    } else {
        departureTime.reverse().insert(0, dateIs + " ");
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        arrivalTime.reverse().insert(0,dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()) +" ");
    }
    dateFormat.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa");
    Date dateOne = dateFormat.parse(departureTime.toString());
    Date dateTwo = dateFormat.parse(arrivalTime.toString());

    DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(dateTwo.getTime() - dateOne.getTime());
    System.out.println(DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(dateTwo.getTime() -
                                                               dateOne.getTime(),
                                                               true, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
    cal1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 4);
    cal2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    System.out.println(((cal1.getTimeInMillis()-cal2.getTimeInMillis())/1000)/3600);
```

Comment: think about the leap seconds... :)